# How to derive through a convolution?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, laplace-transform, convolution

Let $f(t) = \alpha e^{-\beta t}$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are constants

Let $g(t) = y(t)$

Then the resulting convolution $f\ast g$ is:

$$f \ast g = \int_0^t \alpha  e^{-\beta (t-\tau)} y(\tau) d\tau$$

- Does anyone know how one would take the derivative of this
  expression?
- In general, are there rules for taking derivative of $f \ast g$, for
  some given $f,g$?

> Idea: using fundamental theorem of calculus, treat the integrand as a
>   single function $h(t)$
>
> $$\int_0^t \alpha  e^{-\beta (t-\tau)} y(\tau) d\tau = \int_0^t
>  h(\tau) d\tau$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices that one of the two functions is in $L^1$ and the other is in $L^{\infty} \cap C^1$ and its derivative is in $L^{\infty}$. More generally:

> If $f \in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ and $g \in C^k(\Bbb R^d)$, such that $D^{\alpha}g \in L^{\infty}(\Bbb R^d)$ for all $|\alpha| \le k$, then $f \star g \in C^k(\Bbb R^d)$ and: $D^{\alpha}(f \star g) = f \star D^{\alpha} g$.

Where $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_d) \in \Bbb N^d$, $|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_d$, and:

$$D^{\alpha} g := \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} g}{\partial x_1 ^{\alpha_1} \cdots \partial x_d ^{\alpha_d}}$$

This can be proved by induction on $k$. To prove the case $k=1$, we differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: Hi where did you get that theorem from?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Proposition $8.10$, page $242$ in Folland's Real Analysis

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $f',g'$ are both integrable, then: $$(f\ast g)'=f'\ast g=f\ast g'.$$
Basically, whenever $f'\ast g$ and $f\ast g'$ are well-defined, one has the equality above.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using concepts maybe unfamiliar, but also maintain rigor, I'll introduce some lemmas.

Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.  We say that $f$ is **uniformly differentiable** if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that
   $$
    0 < |x-y| < \delta \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} - f'(x)\right| < \epsilon.
  $$
for all $x,y\in[a,b]$.

**Lemma 1**: The function $f$ is uniformly differentiable if and only if it is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$.

*proof:* Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f^{\prime}$ is continuous on a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$, implying that $f^{\prime}$ is uniformly continuous. Then there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$.

Let $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. It immediately follows that $|x-c|<\delta$, meaning that $|f^{\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|=|f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(x)|<\epsilon$.

Now suppose that $f$ is uniformly differentiable. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f^{\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (x,y)$ such that $f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. Note that $|x-c|<\delta$. Then

\begin{align*} |f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(y)| &=|f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(c)+f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(y)|\\
&\leq |f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(c)|+|f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(y)|\\
&<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon
\end{align*}
thus concluding our proof.

**Lemma 2:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Then $f*g$ is continuous.

*proof:* Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a non-degenerate closed bounded interval, there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|g(t)| \leq M$ for all $t \in [a,b]$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then define interval $[x-r,x+r]$. Then let $I=[x-r-a,x+r-b]$. It follows that $x-t \in I$ for all $t \in [a,b]$. It is also clear that Since $f|_{I}$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|< \delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/(m(b-a))$. Let $x,y \in I$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Note that $|(x-t)-(y-t)|<\delta$. Then 
\begin{align*} |f*g(x)-f*g(y)| &=\left|\int_{a}^{b} (f(x-t)-f(y-t))\cdot g(t) dt\right|\\
&\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left|(f(x-t)-f(y-t))\right|\cdot |g(t)| dt\\
&\leq M \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\epsilon}{M(b-a)} dt\\
&=\frac{M \epsilon (b-a)}{M(b-a)}=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

**Proposition 3:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Show that  if $f^{\prime}$ is continuously differentiable, then $f*g$ is differentiable, where $(f*g)^{\prime}(x)=f^{\prime}*g(x)$.

*proof:* Let $\epsilon>0$.  Since $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a non-degenerate closed bounded interval, there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|g(t)| \leq M$ for all $t \in [a,b]$. Then define interval $[x-r,x+r]$. Then let $I=[x-r-a,x+r-b]$. It follows that $x-t \in I$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Since $f^{\prime}$ is continuously differentiable, by *lemma 1*, it is uniformly differentiable on $I$, implying that there exists $\delta$ so that $x,y \in I$  and $|x-y|<\delta$ imply that $|f^{\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|<\frac{\epsilon}{M(b-a)}$. Then, we have that

\begin{align*}|f*g(x)-f*g(y)| &=\left|\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x-t)-f(y-t)}{x-y}\cdot g(t)dt-\int_{a}^{b}f^{\prime}(x-t)g(t)dt\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{a}^{b}(\frac{f(x-t)-f(y-t)}{x-y}-f^{\prime}(x-t))\cdot g(t)dt\right|\\
&\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left|\left(\frac{f(x-t)-f(y-t)}{x-y}-f^{\prime}(x-t)\right)\right|\cdot |g(t)|dt\\
&\leq M \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\epsilon}{M(b-a)} dt\\
&=\frac{M \epsilon (b-a)}{M(b-a)}=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: Eeeek!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. More or less using elementary methods to prove this. It has the advantage that it loosens some of the conditions for defining the derivative. The long and short of it is contained in c.falcon's answer.

Comment: Or Ahmed Hussein's answer, for that matter.